# Kubernetes wildcard 3rd party domain certs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a question regarding Kubernetes and certs. I will use the Kuberentes-dashboard so as to make this simpler

NOTE: its an Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS kubernetes cluster running kubernetes v1.22.8

We use Godadddy, and we have a purchased wildcard certificate. This is what we have used on 100s of websites we host on our internal network.

There are too many examples of config files out there to make any sense of how to achieve this task.

first this is NOT selfsigned, it is not certificate server based in our environment

We have a Godaddy Wilcard certificate which we use for all our webhosting *.domainname.net

One site says do it this way

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-cert
  namespace: default
data:
  tls.crt: domain2023.crt
  tls.key: domain2023.rsa
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

I don't even know if that's correct
another says do it this way

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example-cert  #name of this object
  namespace: default #same namespace as 
spec:
  dnsNames:
    - example.com
  secretName: example-tls-cert
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

This is the service I am unsure how to proceed with this

```
kubectl describe services dashboard
Name:                     dashboard
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=kubernetes-dashboard
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=kubernetes-dashboard
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=kubernetes-dashboard
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=2.7.0
                          helm.sh/chart=kubernetes-dashboard-6.0.0
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=kubernetes-dashboard,app.kubernetes.io/instance=kubernetes-dashboard,app.kubernetes.io/name=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.159.218
IPs:                      10.100.159.218
Port:                     <unset>  8443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30046/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.37.93:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I have tried a few examples I found on line as shown previously
I am trying add our wildcard cert to kubernets so that dashboard and other webservices can use it

This is my dashboard-backend yaml

This works but the site complains about the unsigned certificate:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    # Uncomment next if you use https://cert-manager.io/
    # cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "<YOUR CLUSTER ISSUER>"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - bw-npe.net
    secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-cert
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```

I have our certificate in pfx format I followed some guides to split into crt and an rsa
file

Bottom line I can't get it working...
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: are you trying to implement the end-to-end cert ? your service also running on HTTPS? you have SSL-passthrough:true option so.